# Sonata News Bundle - Add CKEditor

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm a beginner in Symfony and I am trying to set up CKEditor for the Sonata News Bundle.

I have looked everywhere (even on German forums whereas I don't speak German !) but I cannot find any answer anywhere.

Does anyone have a clue or a solution to my question ?

Thank you everyone.

Louis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [`IvoryCKEditorBundle`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/installation.html)

Download the Bundle:

```
composer require egeloen/ckeditor-bundle
```

Register the Bundle, Then, update your app/AppKernel.php

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
            // ...
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you're using Symfony <= 2.8:

```
php app/console ckeditor:install
php app/console assets:install web
```

If you're using Symfony >= 3.0:

```
php bin/console ckeditor:install
php bin/console assets:install web
```

Then [usage](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/config.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it (symfony: 4.3.5, sonata: 3.54.1).

Download ckeditor JS lib and place it inside `public/js` so i.e. you should have the file:

```
your_app/public/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
```

and beside that file dirs: `adapters`, `lang`, `plugins` and `skins` and some js/css/md files.

Then override base sonata edit template with:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

This code will include ckeditor to your pages and should be placed at: `your_app/templates/edit.html.twig`

Then, add to "templates" section `edit:edit.html.twig` so template you created would be used:

```
sonata_admin:
    title: 'Your app Admin'
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list, position: left }
    templates:
        edit: edit.html.twig
```

This is file: `your_app/config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`

Then, when you are adding new field from sonata admin bundle, inside configureFormFields your ckeditor fields should look like:

```
->add('field_name', null, array('attr'=> array('class' => 'ckeditor')))
```

Important part is adding array of attributes with class attribute.
Clear the cache and CKEditor should be working now.